# How to access "pristine", "submitting" and "form.reset" outside the form in react-final-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I would like to show above the form: "You have unsaved changes" (when the form is not pristine) with "Save" (submit) and "Discard" (reset) buttons.

How can I access things like "pristine", "submitting" and "form.reset" outside the form?

I could only find an example with external submit (https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples#external-submit) but these things doesn't seem to follow same patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped my entire component in `<Form>` element. Seems to be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are in a situation where you are not able to encapsulate everything within the `<Form>` tag, you could extract the `form` instance out of the form using `MutableRefs`.

This `form` instance can then be used to access form state, change field values and much more. To know more about the capabilities of `form` instance - [React Final Form - Form API](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi)

Instructions on how to extract the `form` instance - [Access react-final-form values from outside the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117523/access-react-final-form-values-from-outside-the-form/68804555?noredirect=1#comment121604317_68804555)

Answer (score 1):

[Final Form Submit Listener](https://github.com/final-form/final-form-submit-listener)

Try this solution and tell me what

```
const submitListener = createDecorator({
    beforeSubmit: formApi => { 
        alert("go");
        formApi.reset();
    },
    afterSubmitSucceeded: formApi => {  alert("ok") },
    afterSubmitFailed: formApi => {  alert("ko") },
})
```